# Retrieve and Store paypal subscriptions

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, parse-platform, paypal-sandbox

I am working with paypal subscription payments, where when user enter a subscription after signing up.

Below is the paypal code that charges users:

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CA">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value={{currentUser.get('plan')}}>
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="0.01">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">




<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="">
value="">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">

</form>
```

Now I want to store the confirmed payments (i.e. amount, date, etc) into Parse for the current user but not sure how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: `success.php?tx=6BA48179L4889664N&st=Pending&amt=0%2e01&cc=CAD&cm=&item_number=&sig=Hfh95Y%2fv8XTcl9zZasPjTwswbzJ2CRgSxRX%2f5U%2fmtDxQQk1cCOpuUH4awkCCGSQsI%2fgQnNeg%2bKUa7a9p0UPwNHQgL%2bST1aonNptQBSXKCVqAlVGY9QMb%2bQJJk2QMxttgKxysFZnBaKxBxLl8E2vbtLNsDflWf%2fJfT2eCMnSlzSc%3d`   , I need to grab the amont, currency, and tx I have tried to do it using

```
<?php
//Getting payment details from paypal
$amount = $_GET[‘amt’];
$currency = $_GET[‘cc’];
$trx_id = $_GET[‘tx’];
$invoice = mt_rand();
//inserting the payment to table


echo "$trx_id";
```

`?>` but its not working

Comment: Your question is a little confusing because "recurring payments" is actually the name of a similar but different PayPal product; your code snippet shows that you are using PayPal's subscriptions product. Also, it is not clear (at least to me) whether you want to store the details of the subscription when it is agreed to, or you want to store a new record when each payment of the subscription is made. If you can clarify, that may help someone who knows Parse (I do not) help you more easily.

Comment: I should have clarified. I  am using PayPal's subscriptions and want to store the subscrption details when its agreed to. Parse is just a database storage, which is not my concern. My concern is how do i retrieve the purchase information of the user. all i need is the variables like amount =x, date=x and from there I can store it through parse

Comment: OK, will answer below then on that basis...

Answer (score 0):

PayPal can provide information back to you about the subscription using the PDT/IPN variables described here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB0901HT

If you are getting the subscription details from PayPal you should use PDT or IPN to ensure the post back to you is legitimate.

However, since you must have had the subscription details in the first place in order to send them to PayPal, you may find it easier/more reliable to record the information yourself in its original format than to reconstruct it from PayPal's variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and it makes a lot of sense. My whole dilemna resolve in setting up IPN. I have two pages, the payment page where the subscription form is displayed, and the success page, the page that redirects the user after a succesful purchase and in where I want to grab these variables. I read over the guide but a bit of guidance would be useful.

Comment: Are you asking for how to transfer the information between your two pages, or how to set up IPN? If the former, your choices are server-side (e.g. database) or client-side (cookie) storage, or most frequently these days both: the info is in your database, keyed by the session id in the cookie. More "how" than this would depend heavily on your web framework since they all generally wrap this up somehow for you. If the latter, google should find examples of IPN or PDT setup in most common languages/frameworks; I would recommend hunting one up & then seeing how far it gets you.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get PDT to work, where the url containing various variables was produced. My issue now is in displaying it and did try a workaround. I have included an update under the initial section of my post